# Program loses memory references as it progresses

Tags: c, memory-management, pthreads

I have a project that consists of several processes running in different computers. It is similar to a "OS Simulator", mainly task scheduling and resource allocation.

There's a main process, "Platform" or "Server", that planifies/schedules the different processes that connect to it, by using a queue with the available processes that are ready to execute.

As time passes however, the pointers lose the memory address of some of them, or the reference to it, or the memory to which it points is either freed or just used for some other variable.  This then leads to the process that's supposed to run just halting and waiting for the Platform to schedule it, which never happens because the element from the queue no longer references the process(which we handle with file descriptors). Is there anyway to prevent this from happening??

Here's the portion of the code where we think the problem is:

```
response = string_substring_from(response, sizeof(FREERESC));

char** data = string_split(response, COMA);

t_queue *temporaryQueue = queue_create();
t_scheduler_queue *queues = dictionary_get(levels_queues, data[0]);

pthread_mutex_lock(queues->mutex);

t_queue *anotherQueue = queue_create();

long o = 0;

if (queue_size(queues->character_queue) > 0)
{
    log_info(log, "Mas de un personaje listo");

    for (o = 0; o < queue_size(queues->character_queue); o++)
    {
        personaje_planificador *personajeEnLista = queue_pop(
        queues->character_queue);
        personaje_planificador *nuevoPersonaje = (personaje_planificador*) malloc(sizeof(personaje_planificador));
        // long *hola = (long*) malloc(sizeof(long));
        // memcpy(hola, &(personajeEnLista->fd), sizeof(long));
        // nuevoPersonaje->fd = hola;
        nuevoPersonaje->fd = personajeEnLista->fd;
        nuevoPersonaje->nombre = string_from_format("%s", personajeEnLista->nombre);
        queue_push(anotherQueue, nuevoPersonaje);
    }
}

char** simbolos;

long j = 2;
t_dictionary *recursosDisponibles = dictionary_create();

for (j = 2; j < list_size(queues->simbolos) + 2; j++)
{
    simbolos = string_split(data[j], DOSPUNTOS);
    long *temporary = (long*) malloc(sizeof(long));
    *temporary = atoi(simbolos[1]);
    dictionary_put(recursosDisponibles, simbolos[0], temporary);
}

if (queue_size(queues->blocked_queue) > 0)
{
    log_info(log, "Mas de un personaje bloqueado");

    long i = 0;
    long k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < queue_size(queues->blocked_queue); i++)
    {
        blocked_character *blockedCharacter = queue_pop(queues->blocked_queue);

        for (k = 0; k < list_size(queues->simbolos); k++)
        {
            if (blockedCharacter->recurso == ((char*) list_get(queues->simbolos, k))[0])
            {
                if (giveResource(queues, dictionary_get(recursosDisponibles, list_get(queues->simbolos, k)), blockedCharacter) == 1)
                {
                    personaje_planificador *nuevoPersonajeAgain = (personaje_planificador*) malloc(sizeof(personaje_planificador));
                    nuevoPersonajeAgain->fd =
                    blockedCharacter->personaje->fd;
                    nuevoPersonajeAgain->nombre = blockedCharacter->personaje->nombre;
                    queue_push(temporaryQueue, nuevoPersonajeAgain);

                    //TODO log
                }
                else
                {
                    queue_push(queues->blocked_queue, blockedCharacter);
                }
            }
        }

        k = 0;
    }
}

o = 0;

for (o = 0; o < queue_size(temporaryQueue); o++)
{
    queue_push(anotherQueue, queue_pop(temporaryQueue));
}

queues->character_queue = anotherQueue;

pthread_mutex_unlock(queues->mutex);

t_level_address *addresses = (t_level_address*) dictionary_get(levelsMap, data[0]);

char **levelSocket = string_split(addresses->nivel, DOSPUNTOS);

long fdNivel = openSocketClient(levelSocket[1], levelSocket[0]);

sendMessage(fdNivel, stringRecursos(queues->simbolos, recursosDisponibles, atoi(data[1])));

free(recursosDisponibles);

log_info(log, "Liberar recursos.");

if (flagTerminoUnPersonaje == TRUE)
{
    executeKoopa(niveles, levels_queues, orquestador_config);
}
```

Let me know if a portion of the code is unclear (it has some things written in Spanish), or if you need another part where you think the problem may be in.

Comment: run your program with valgrind.  it sounds like you've got writes to incorrect parts of memory.  valgrind will show errors you can fix.

Comment: How do we reproduce the problem using the code you've posted?

Comment: Forgot the language tag for "Spanish", as well as "C" :-)

Comment: Which pointers are going wrong, and what happens when you simplify the code? Can you post a minimal complete example?

Comment: asking someone to hand simulate non-english code that may or may not actually contain the problem isn't a way to get help at stack overflow.  You'll need to post working code that demonstrates the problem.  Or hire a consultant.

Comment: Valgrind is a good reco...if no access, then..One recommendation is to limit the threads to 1 and run this through gdb. I.e. make sure that the base case works first before adding more parallelism.  Second would be to add a queue verifier i.e. test the queue length against the num elements that are supposed to be in the queue before and after major queue events like ins/del. Third would be to keep a log of allocs and frees of memory and see if you have a double free. Fourth is to add a funny code to the freed memory, before freeing it...hopefully, it becomes easy to catch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody mentioned "ValGrind" in one of the comments.

Try one of the products mentioned here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BoundsChecker

You should be able to find a free trial if not an outright free version.  (it's been about 10 years since I regularly maintained other people's C and had to use Purify and Insure to hunt down this kind of aliasing and leaking)

Comment: this isn't really an answer and should be a comment -- and already has been by others.